# jQueryUI inline DatePicker doesn't work until after I change month

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using an inline Datepicker with jquery 1.7.2 and jqueryui 1.8.20. the problem I have is that the following doesn't work until I change the month in the datepicker, then it works fine. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
       dateFormat: 'D, dd M yy',
       minDate:0,
       onSelect: function(dateText, inst){ 
            //$('.field_pickDate').html(dateText);
            alert('boo');
            //console.log(dateText);
        } 
    });
```

`dateFormat` and `minDate` are both working but the `onSelect` event isn't firing from the get-go.

Comment: What exactly does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: Sorry, it means clicking on a date doesn't select it or make the alert appear (or anything in the callback execute).

Comment: Update: If I replace the `div#datepicker` element with `input#datepicker` it works normally. However its a mobile project so the inline makes more sense in the UI.

Comment: Are you using the ID "datepicker" more than once on your page?

Comment: No, although I am using 2 jqueryui buttonsets on the page as well

Comment: Can you post your HTML and/or create a jsFiddle showing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default functionality of that event.

Its fired when the user "selects" something in the date picker.

To call an event on click (before you show the date Picker) you can use "beforeShow".

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
       dateFormat: 'D, dd M yy',
       minDate:0,
       beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
             alert("Fired on click, before the picker is shown");
       },
       onSelect: function(dateText, inst){ 
            //$('.field_pickDate').html(dateText);
            alert('boo');
            //console.log(dateText);
        } 
    });
```

Here's a JSFiddle example of it working with your code.

http://jsfiddle.net/applehat/jukJa/1/

You could always just add another event onto the text box, such as `$('#datepicker').select(function(){ /* do something */ });`
as well, if you want to detect them selecting the field.

================= EDIT ===============

Since you are using it as an Inline element, Im not sure what your problem is. I have updated my JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/applehat/jukJa/2/

Everything works as expected here, so maybe you have other code causing issues?

Comment: This is an inline datepicker. It's attached to  div#datepicker as opposed to an input

Comment: I suspect this has something to do with it too but it is designed to be attached inline: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline.

Comment: Updated my JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/applehat/jukJa/2/) - That seems to work fine. Without seeing all the code, I can just assume something else is causing an issue.

Comment: Also, check http://jsfiddle.net/applehat/jukJa/3/ for a closer example of what I believe you are trying to do.

Comment: The datepicker was firing before the ready event. The webapp runs on a complex jQuery based, phonegap compatible MVC-style framework. Changing the month presumably initialises the datepicker, hiding the event order mistiming.